# Globally modify requests in a central place

Tags: python, python-requests

I've been tasked to update an existing Python module that sends requests to an external API in many different places with `requests`. That is, in this module there are at least 50 usages of `requests` to send requests to said API.

There was a change in the API that requires a header to be added to all requests. Before manually adding the header to all 50 requests, I was wondering if it is possible to define some kind of "middleware" (as for example in [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/middleware/)) that could add the header for all requests at once.

Is something like this possible with `requests`?

Comment: In all of these 50 usages, are all the headers exactly the same, or do some contain different ones? If they're all the same, you could have the module read the headers from one central configuration file, that way whenever you need to make any changes you only have to modify one file.

Comment: Have you tried [requests-middleware](https://pypi.org/project/requests-middleware/)?

Comment: @crissal I've had a look at it, but the repo suggests it is currently not maintained.

Answer (score 1):

You can monkey-patch the `requests.request` function with a wrapper that updates the dict specified by the `headers` arguments with additional entries.

Below is an example that would force all requests to have a header of `User-Agent` with the value `My Browser`:

```
import requests
import inspect

def override_headers(self, func, global_headers):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        bound = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        bound.apply_defaults()
        bound.arguments.setdefault('headers', {}).update(global_headers)
        return func(*bound.args, **bound.kwargs)

    sig = inspect.signature(func)
    return wrapper

requests.request = override_headers(requests.request, {'User-Agent': 'My Browser'})
```

Comment: In my case, I had to modify the following line for it to work as expected:

bound.arguments['kwargs'].setdefault('headers', {}).update({'myheader': 123})